# Check columns, if one is bigger or equal to the adjacent cell in column A, style it differently

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 10 columns with price data in.

Column A has my product SKU

Column B - has the cost price of a product

The other columns have other prices in them.

Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17PLI_d_05uYnzOt2yL4ZQA3XB89rIz9vQJnIOBidMz8/edit?usp=sharing

**I want to go through each cell in a row and see if any of the prices listed are less than, or equal to, the cost price in Cell A.**

How would I write this in Google Sheets?

Comment: I think I have a couple of ideas on how to do this.  Could you make that sample editable? or maybe File>Make a Copy first and make that editable?  Just so i can demo/test a couple ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct way to do this is the following formula:

**=$D2:$K2<=$B2**

Answer (score 0):

To check if there is any price below (or equal) to a certain value, you could check the minimum price and compare that. So use the [`MIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094017?hl=en) function and compare that with the value at `B2`.

```
=MIN(D2:K2)<= B2
```

[image: Example of work]

---

You have posted a solution but you are comparing a range with a value, and for me it does not work.